# What's the best way to fetch a POP3 server for new mails every 15 minutes?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper, delayed-job

I'm developing an app that needs to fetch a POP3 account every 5-15 minutes to check for new email and process it. I have written all the code except for the part where it automatically runs every 5-15 minutes.

I'm using Sinatra, DataMapper and hosting on Heroku which means cron jobs are out of the question, because Heroku only provides hourly cron jobs at best.

I have looked into Delayed::Job which doesn't natively support Sinatra nor DataMapper but there are workarounds [for](https://github.com/vanpelt/delayed_job) [both](https://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-dj). Since my Ruby knowledge is limited I couldn't find a way to merge these two forks into one working Delayed::Job for Sinatra/DataMapper solution.

Initially I used [Mailman](https://github.com/titanous/mailman) to check for emails which has built-in polling and runs continuously, but since it's not Rack-based it doesn't run on Heroku.

Any pointers on where to go next? Before you say: a different webhost, I should add I really prefer to stick with Heroku because of its ease of use (except of course, for the above issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku supports [CloudMailin](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudmailin)

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is to write your code contained in a loop, then sleep at the bottom of it for however long you want:

Untested sample code...

```
loop do
    do_something_way_cool()
    sleep 5 * 60 # it's in minutes
end
```

If it has to be contained in the main body of the app then use a [`Thread`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Thread.html) to wrap it so the thread does the work. You'll need to figure out your shared data structures to transfer the data out of the loop. [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Queue.html) is your friend there.